# How to count the number of files with a specific extension in all folders and subfolders

Tags: python, file, count

Quick question. I have a folder with 20 sub-folders. I want to count all the files with a .xlsx in all the folders and sub-subfodlers etc. I need to use os.walk to make sure my code literately walk through every folder/sub-folder possible. This is the code I have right now. Howeverr, I get an `Invalid Syntax`

```
a = os.getcwd()             
list1 = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(a):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.txt'):
            list1 = (os.path.join(root, file)
            a = sum([len(list1)])
            print(a)
```

Does someone maybe has an easier or prettier code to fix this problem?

Comment: There is a parenthesis missing. `list1 = os.path.join(root, file)`. And you probably want to append the path to list1.

Comment: @rbeucher I actually figured it out. If you can accept my answer below other people may learn from it as well. Thank you.

Comment: Well I can't accept the answer for you...

Comment: @rbeucher to bad:( whats the reason for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have one parenthesis missing and you need to append the path to the list.

So I would try something like:

```py
a = os.getcwd()             
list1 = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(a):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.txt'):
            list1.append(os.path.join(root, file))
            
print(len(list1))
```

Comment: Your code works. But you need to delete the ``os.getcwd()`` and use a full path instead. My current working directory is not the same as the place where my files resist, thats why. But thank you!

Answer (score 1):

(you guys answered while I was working on my contribution, I still post it in case in can help other users understand the issues in the question post)

Your approach using os.walk is, to me, the good one. Though, I found a few issues with your code:

1. after entering the if statement, you have a (useless) opening parenthesis that is never closed;
2. you need to use the list method .append to extend the content of a list with the path of your .xlsx file, what you are doing right now is replacing for each 'file' the content of list1;
3. you don't need to apply 'sum' on 'len' as len() already returns the number of elements in your list, and you need to run 'len' outside your loops after your list is complete.

This all results in the code given as an answer by @rbeucher